# Migrate site using yii from server to local machine (using xamp). Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I need to make some modifications on a website which is made with the yii framework. I want to make a local copy from the server to make modifications here than upload them to the server.
I downloaded the code trough FTP to my XAMP htdocs folder, copied the database, and changed the database connectionString in the main.php file

However when I get the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in          C:\xamppNew\htdocs\smuff\protected\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php on line 4
```

Can anyone help, are there some migration steps when moving the site to a different location? I could not find any documentation about migrating a yii site.

I use PHP Version 5.4.7
I did download the yii framework and created a new site with it, and that does work correctly.

In my main.php the

```
   'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```

lines are there and the
The c:\xamppNew\htdocs\smuff\protected\frontend\components\Controller.php where the Controller class is defined is loaded (I added an `echo "here";exit;` and it showed the correct `here` than exited).

Answer (score 0):

the usual path for the conmponents in a yii application is protected/component.

Try:

```
'import'=>array(
'application.frotend.models.*',
'application.frontend.components.*',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I use php 5.5 and Yii 1.1.16

php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

This config generated fatal error. But if you use:

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR|E_WARNING|E_PARSE|E_NOTICE|E_CORE_WARNING|E_COMPILE_WARNING|E_USER_ERROR|E_USER_WARNING|E_USER_NOTICE|E_DEPRECATED|E_USER_DEPRECATED
```

without **E_STRICT** all be alright

it's magic
I was really surprised